# Table View only loads if I put phone in landscape mode

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

I have a custom table view, which when I run the app, shows up blank, like it hasnt been loaded, but when I tilt my phone to landscape mode, the entries appear, which really doesnt make sense to me. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here is my code

```
 import UIKit
 import Alamofire
 import ObjectMapper
 class LotteryTableViewController: UITableViewController {
let lotteryMachine = LotteryMachine()

var currentStandings: [Team] = []
var draftStandings: [Team] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let headers = [
        "User-agent": "LotteryMachine/1.0 (nilayneeranjun24@gmail.com)",
               ]
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://erikberg.com/nba/standings.json",headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                let parentJson = Mapper<Standings>().map(response.2.value)
               let standingsArray: [Team] = parentJson!.standing!
                    self.currentStandings=standingsArray
                    self.draftStandings=self.lotteryMachine.setPossibleCombinations(standingsArray)
                    self.draftStandings=self.lotteryMachine.setDraftPositions(self.draftStandings)
                    print (self.draftStandings.toJSON())
                }

    }




    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return draftStandings.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "LotteryTableViewCell"


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LotteryTableViewCell


   let position = self.draftStandings[indexPath.row].draftingPosition!

    let teamName = self.draftStandings[indexPath.row].lastName!
   let record = String(self.draftStandings[indexPath.row].won!) + "-" + String(self.draftStandings[indexPath.row].lost!)

    let player = "Ben Simmons"
    cell.position.text = String(position)
    cell.teamName.text = teamName
    cell.record.text = String(record)
    cell.player.text = player
   cell.teamLogo.image = UIImage(named: "lakers")



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: Have you checked its CSS . Generally in CSS we can hide an element for a particular landscape /portrait mode using media queries.

Comment: how did you set your constraint? try `trailing space` in stead of `leading space`

Comment: Have you reload the table view in `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: Do you mean the navigation toolbar is there and there are empty rows (but divider lines), or just plain white?

Comment: there are divider lines and no navigation toolbar

Comment: Are you using Size Classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Alamofire.request` is async in nature. So when the table first loads, the request is still executing and your `draftStandings` doesn't have any data. When you rotate, the table is reloaded and by that time `draftStandings` does have some data already which the table shows.

Try adding a `tableView.reloadData()` after setting the `draftStandings` in the request response.

Comment: yup, that was it. Thanks

Comment: lets say I wanted to call the http request before the tabs are loaded and pass the standingsArray to both of my tabs. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest waiting for a n/w operation to complete before you load your user interface (which you will have to do if you go ahead with such an implementation). Async calls are always preferred